# How does the script compute an object containing the frequency specified in a json data

Tags: javascript

I have a data json format (population.json) :

```
[
{
    "Population": "100",
    "City": "London",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "20.55"
},
{
    "Population": "500",
    "City": "Manchester",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "26.55"
},
{
    "Population": "800",
    "City": "Manchester",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "26.55"
},
{
    "Population": "800",
    "City": "London",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "26.55"
},
]
```

I want to find out if there is a frequency Population > 100 in the city of Manchester and frequency Population > 100 for all city ?

I've tried using the following script:

```
<body>
 <p>
 frequency of Population > 100 in Manchester : <span id="population"></span>
 </p>
 </body>
```

for javascript :

```
<script>
var jsonData = 'population.json';
            function getJSONValue(fileJSON) {
                var value = $.ajax({
                    url: fileJSON,
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
                return value
            }
            populationData = getJSONValue(jsonData)
            var populationDataJSON = JSON.parse(populationData)
for (k = 0; k < populationDataJSON.length; k++) {
                var population_data = parseInt(populationDataJSON[k].population)
                var Coordinate = new L.latLng(([populationDataJSON[k].Lat, populationDataJSON[k].Long]))
                if (population > 100) {              }
                else { }
            }
```

How do I complete this script to get the results I want it

Comment: Don't use synchronous AJAX - it's a really bad idea. Soon it won't even be supported. If you're using jQuery, use callbacks or deferred objects.

Comment: `async: false` is being deprecated by libraries and browsers, and it is detrimental to the user experience.  You should not rely upon it.

Comment: Can you help me solve it if I don't use Ajax

Comment: if async: false is being deprecated by libraries and browsers, what should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` method on your array like this:

```js
var data = [
{
    "Population": "100",
    "City": "London",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "20.55"
},
{
    "Population": "500",
    "City": "Manchester",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "26.55"
},
{
    "Population": "800",
    "City": "Manchester",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "26.55"
},
{
    "Population": "800",
    "City": "London",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
     "Lat": "26.55"
},
]

var higherThan100 = data.filter( e => e.Population > 100)
var lowerThan500 = data.filter( e => e.Population < 500)

console.log(higherThan100)
console.log(lowerThan500)
```

Comment: Thank You, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `forEach`:

```js
const populationDataJSON = [{
    "Population": "100",
    "City": "London",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
    "Lat": "20.55"
  },
  {
    "Population": "500",
    "City": "Manchester",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
    "Lat": "26.55"
  },
  {
    "Population": "800",
    "City": "Manchester",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
    "Lat": "26.55"
  },
  {
    "Population": "800",
    "City": "London",
    "Date": "2020-08-07",
    "Long": "70",
    "Lat": "26.55"
  },
];

populationDataJSON.forEach(k => {
  const population_data = k["Population"];

  if (population_data > 100) console.log(k);
})
```

`k` here represents each object instance, so you can access its properties like you would with: `populationDataJSON[k]`.